# Visual Studio debug continuing unhandled exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I found a strange behaviour in Visual Studio (2008 and 2013).

Lets start with a testcode:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string readFile()
{
    std::fstream f;
    f.open("not_good_file.txt", std::fstream::in);

    if (!f.good())
        throw std::exception("unable to read file");

    f.seekg(0, f.end);
    std::streamoff len = f.tellg();
    f.seekg(0, f.beg);

    string result(len, '\0');
    f.read(&result[0], len);
    f.close();
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "before exception" << endl;
    readFile();
    cout << "after exception" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When running without debugger the application aborts as expected but when I reach an unguarded exception while debugging, the known message window displays to tell me about the uncaught exception. I get the option to `break` which shows the line where the exception was thrown (if available) and the option `continue` which (as the name states) continues the application.

The result is, that code directly after the exception is executed which means that `f.tellg()` returns `-1` which is not a valid length for `std::string`.

Why is that happening?

Comment: What did you expect to happen otherwise? You ask the application to continue and it continues? Also in production code you probably should be checking if `len` is positive anyway before implicitly casting it to an unsigned integer.

Comment: i would have expected that the message popping up is just a reminder and when using `continue` it will do what it would do without the debugger (in that case abort)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The result is, that code directly after the exception is executed wich means that f.tellg() returns -1 wich is no valid length for std::string.

The debugger gives you the options to run as if the exception was not there (continue) or to break at the exception site (break).

Normally, when you choose to continue, the application should jump to the catch block for the exception (or to stack unwindingm and *then* to the catch block). You have no catch block though, so the application should jump to `std::terminate` (and end execution).

Having the IDE give you the option to "continue" and that meaning "call std::terminate" is nuts (because then, "continue" would effectively mean "stop"). So in this case, "continue" means "continue execution as if the exception was not there", not "continue execution to terminate application".

Comment: thanks for clarification. was not aware that `continue` means `ignore exception`.

Comment: Continuation after exception can lead to unforeseen consequences. It's not right that it's allowed.